# Error while uploading theme to wordpress on Azure

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

I have created a wordpress web app on Azure using gallery provided by Azure. I am trying to add a new theme on that web app using .zip file i have for the theme.

After I upload the theme it gives me following error every single time.

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I have even deleted and re created the web app but getting the same result. Is there any issue with wordpress setup provided by Azure?

Comment: Do you occur the same issue if you upload any other theme?

Comment: I uploaded the theme via FTP and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

it was the web.config file.here was the fix that worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="wp-includes/ms-files.php?file={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">

<match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
</conditions>
<action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule 7" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why do these rewrite rules work? Why doesn't it work if you don't add them?